# Suma recurrente por grupo

Tags: python, dataframe

```
Tengo el siguiente dataframe, open_positions[['ticket','profit','comment']]:
ticket es int
profit es float
comment es string

       ticket  profit      comment
0   298086050    6.31             
1   298112936    6.45             
2   298114176    5.60             
3   298121693    6.01             
4   298180274   -4.43             
5   298180285    3.20  CT298180274
6   298180671    3.77             
7   298197488   -4.11             
8   298197491    2.54  CT298197488
9   298197735    3.20             
10  298204286  -16.40  CT298197491
11  298204531  -17.72  CT298180285
12  298212470   -3.52             
13  298212478    1.54  CT298212470
14  298224916   10.08  CT298204286
15  298226008   21.50  CT298204531
16  298287325    0.39             
17  298300506   -1.99             
18  298303067   -0.04
```

Como podría obtener un dataframe que indicara el resumen de los tickets que sumaran positivo en profit, pero que tuvieran su ticket dentro de un comentario, de hecho pueden tener varios niveles por ejemplo:
el ticket 298180274
tiene dependientes a:
298180285
298204531
298226008

Cada uno está contenido dentro de comment sucesivamente en éste caso la suma de profit da: 2.55 (positivo)

```
ticket      profit    comment
298180274    -4.43    
298180285     3.20    CT298180274
298204531   -17.72    CT298180285
298226008    21.50    CT298204531
```

El cual SI cumple la condición que sea mayor que cero.

y así sucesivamente: seguirían:  298197488, 298212470.

Que son los que tienen dependientes por decirlo así, o sea que el tiket está en el comentario, los principales serían los que no tienen comentario pero siguen sus dependientes en los comentarios.

Los valores están cambiando continuamente y hay que estar evaluandolos, si se pudiera elegir un método que no tardara, pues el dataframe pyede llegar a tener hasta 1000 elementos ó mas. y la velocidad del proceso de ese calculo es crucial.

La idea es obtener un resumen  de los que su suma sea mayor a cero por cada grupo de principal y sus dependientes. En este caso sería:

298180274, 298197488, 298212470, los cuales sus sumas por grupo de los que son mayores que cero, es uno 298180274, por lo tanto el dataframe resultante sería.

```
  ticket  profit      comment
298180274    2.55
```

Agradezco de antemano la colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es bastante complejo en general, y más aún en particular si intentas resolverlo mediante pandas.

La complicación nace del hecho de que no está claro en qué orden pueden aparecer los tickets y sus relaciones a través del campo "comment". Yo entiendo que el campo "comment" en realidad ayuda a crear una especie de "cadena" de tickets, pues cada ticket puede "señalar" cuál es su predecesor en la cadena a través del campo comment.

Así, la serie de tickets que muestras tú de ejemplo:

```
ticket      profit    comment
298180274    -4.43    
298180285     3.20    CT298180274
298204531   -17.72    CT298180285
298226008    21.50    CT298204531
```

cumplen esta relación que yo digo. El 298180274, al no tener nada en "comment", no tiene "predecesor". En cambio el 298180285 indicaría que su predecesor es el 298180274, y así sucesivamente.

El 298226008 sería el útimo de esta cadena porque no aparece después ningún otro que le tenga en su campo "comment".

Por tanto un primer problema es encontrar esas "cadenas de tokens" dentro de tu dataframe. Ya que no se puede saber de antemano si un token cocreto será el último de su cadena hasta haber procesado todos los existentes (pues podría aparecer como "comment" en cualquiera de ellos), no se me ocurre cómo poder usar un `groupby()` para crear ese tipo de agrupaciones.

Por tanto no voy a usar pandas para encontrar la solución, sino estructuras de datos python, en particular listas y conjuntos. No me gusta mucho esta solución, debido a que estaré iterando mediante código python en lugar de usar las primitivas paralelizables de pandas, pero la verdad no veo otra solución. Al menos evitaré los bucles anidados y usaré el tipo de datos `set()` para agilizar las búsquedas, lo que será muy eficiente. La complejidad algorítmica de mi propuesta será O(N) si no me equivoco.

### Mi propuesta

Es enrevesada, no lo voy a negar. Lo primero es encontrar las agrupaciones adecuadas, o "cadenas de tickets" como las denominé en la introducción.

Para ello operaré solo con las filas que tengan algo en el comment (lo que me va a disminuir mucho la cantidad de filas a procesar) y para cada una de ellas extraeré tanto el valor del ticket como el de su comentario, para meter ambos en un conjunto si es la primera vez que aparecen. En cambio, si cualquiera de los dos ya había aparecido previamente, lo meteré en el mismo conjunto en que habían aparecido.

Al terminar tendré en cada conjunto los tokens que componen esa "cadena de tokens". Este es mi código:

```
sets = []
for index, comment in df.comment.dropna().items():
  ticket = df.loc[index].ticket
  ticket_comentario = int(comment[2:])
  aux = set((ticket, ticket_comentario))  # Creo un conjunto con estos dos
  # Ahora miraré si ya habían aparecido
  for conjunto in sets:
    if conjunto & aux:  # Intersección de conjuntos, no vacía si alguno ya estaba
      conjunto |= aux   # Añadirlos al conjunto con la operación | (unión)
      break             # y salir de este bucle
  else:                 # Si el bucle se ha agotado sin hacer break
    sets.append(aux)    # Meto el conjunto de dos elementos como uno nuevo
```

A pesar de lo aparentemente enrevesado del algoritmo, funciona correctamente. Aplicandolo a tu dataset, una vez termina este bucle (que debería ser bastante rápìdo), tenemos ya separados en varios conjuntos las diferentes "cadenas de tokens":

```
>>> print(sets)

[{298180274, 298180285, 298204531, 298226008},
 {298197488, 298197491, 298204286, 298224916},
 {298212470, 298212478}]
```

Ahi tienes las tres agrupaciones de tickets buscadas. Ahora, para cada uno de esos conjuntos, se calcularía la suma de sus profits. Almacenaré los resultados en una lista de diccionarios para después poder crear un dataframe con el resultado.

```
resultados = []
for conjunto in sets:
  ticket = min(conjunto)
  profit = df[df.ticket.isin(conjunto)].profit.sum()
  comment = df[df.ticket==ticket].comment.values[0]
  resultados.append({"ticket": ticket, "profit": profit, "comment": comment})
```

Una vez terminado este bucle, podemos convertir el resultado en dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(resultados)
      ticket  profit comment
0  298180274    2.55    None
1  298197488   -7.89    None
2  298212470   -1.98    None
```

Naturalmente obtener solo los positivos es trivial:

```
>>> r = pd.DataFrame(resultados)
>>> r[r.profit>0]

      ticket  profit comment
0  298180274    2.55    None
```

No sé si este algoritmo será lo bastante rápido para tus necesidades. Espero que sí, pues he intentado varias optimizaciones para reducir el número de iteraciones y la complejidad de las búsquedas. En cualquier caso dudo que, aún usando funciones puras de pandas, pueda encontrarse una solución mucho más rápida.

### Ampliación solicitada

Para añadir al dataframe de resultados otra columna que contenga los tickets que forman parte del "conjunto", la solución es bastante sencilla. Puesto que en la lista `sets` tenemos precisamente cada conjunto, basta añadirlo a los diccionarios finales en base a los cuales construimos el dataframe. Es decir:

```
resultados = []
for conjunto in sets:
  ticket = min(conjunto)
  profit = df[df.ticket.isin(conjunto)].profit.sum()
  comment = df[df.ticket==ticket].comment.values[0]
  tickets = sorted(list(conjunto))
  resultados.append({"ticket": ticket, "profit": profit, "comment": comment, "tickets": tickets})
```

Y así, el dataframe resultante sería ahora:

```
>>> r = pd.DataFrame(resultados)
>>> r[r.profit>0]

      ticket  profit comment                                       tickets
0  298180274    2.55    None  [298180274, 298180285, 298204531, 298226008]
```

Donde puedes observar cómo en la nueva columna "tickets" aparece la lista de tickets que han dado lugar a ese profit.

Comment: Todo checo tal como lo pusiste, lo voy a implementar, solo una cuestion adicional, podría mostrarse como un dataframe el conjunto que origina el resultado positivo? en este caso obtenemos el que origina y su profit positivo, pero podriamos tener todos los tikets que lo originan, a la ultima impresion: 0  298180274    2.55    None, agregarle un dataframe que sean 298180274, 298204531, 298226008, 298180285.  Agradeciendo la atenciòn.

Comment: ¿Cómo agregando un dataframe? Querrás decir agregar una columna? Que contenga la lista de tickets?

Comment: Así es un dataframe que contenga los tikets de cada suma positiva.